# .Net application - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Hello guys I have a couple of questions regarding the deployment of .net application.
When I tried to access the site I got a 500.19-Internal Server Error(it's shown on the image). I'm doing troubleshooting for a couple of hours without result.

1. Do I need to run the main application in wwwroot?

- If I run the application I can access it via provided link (localhost:5000) then the application is working with the DB smoothly.

2. Do I need to enable port 5000 so I can be able to access the site?
3. asp.net has wwwroot folder for the css/js/etc.. does it make conflict
   with server wwwroot folder?

Any help is appreciated

*The application is .net6.0

In the IIS:
Default site is set on :80 with path \inetpub\wwwroot

Before Publish, this is how the application is configured:
Configuration: Release
Target Framework: net6.0
Deployment Mode: Self-contained
Target Runtime: win-x64

Server:
Windows Server 2022

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">

    <system.webServer>

      <handlers>

        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />

      </handlers>

      <aspNetCore processPath=".\ODWE.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />

    </system.webServer>

  </location>

    <system.webServer>

        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="localhost:5000" httpResponseStatus="PermRedirect" />

    </system.webServer>

</configuration>

<!--ProjectGuid: ef59-->
```

[localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjsJt.png)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="http://localhost:80/favicon.ico"
siteId="1"
appPoolId="DefaultAppPool"
processId="8080"
verb="GET"
remoteUserName=""
userName=""
tokenUserName="NT AUTHORITY\IUSR"
authenticationType="anonymous"
activityId="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
statusCode="500.19"
triggerStatusCode="500.19"
timeTaken="15"
xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>0</Level>
<Opcode>1</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
<Data Name="SiteId">1</Data>
<Data Name="AppPoolId">DefaultAppPool</Data>
<Data Name="ConnId">805306384</Data>
<Data Name="RawConnId">805306384</Data>
<Data Name="RequestURL">http://localhost:80/favicon.ico</Data>
<Data Name="RequestVerb">GET</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">;
<EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>5</Level>
<Opcode>4</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
<Data Name="ModuleName">FailedRequestsTracingModule</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
<Keywords>
<Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
</Keywords>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">;
<EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>5</Level>
<Opcode>5</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
<Data Name="ModuleName">FailedRequestsTracingModule</Data>
<Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END</Opcode>
<Keywords>
<Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
</Keywords>
<freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">;
<EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>5</Level>
<Opcode>4</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
<Data Name="ModuleName">RequestMonitorModule</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
<Keywords>
<Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
</Keywords>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">;
<EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>5</Level>
<Opcode>5</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
<Data Name="ModuleName">RequestMonitorModule</Data>
<Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END</Opcode>
<Keywords>
<Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
</Keywords>
<freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">;
<EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>5</Level>
<Opcode>4</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
<Data Name="ModuleName">IsapiFilterModule</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
<Keywords>
<Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
</Keywords>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">;
<EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>4</Level>
<Opcode>13</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
</EventData>
<RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
<Opcode>FILTER_PREPROC_HEADERS_START</Opcode>
<Keywords>
<Keyword>Filter</Keyword>
</Keywords>
</RenderingInfo>
<ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">;
<EventGuid>{00237F0D-73EB-4BCF-A232-126693595847}</EventGuid>
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">;
<System>
<Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
<EventID>0</EventID>
<Version>1</Version>
<Level>0</Level>
<Opcode>1</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x8</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2022-07-22T06:46:48.360Z"/>
<Correlation ActivityID="{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
<Execution ProcessID="8080" ThreadID="1304"/>
<Computer>SRVSITE40</Computer>
</System>
<EventData>
<Data Name="ContextId">{4000001A-0001-FD00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
<Data Name="FilterName">C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll</Data>
........
</ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: I would suggest checking the hints shown in the error page under "Most likely causes" and "Things you can try". Start there and then come back to us if it is still not working. The error states a configuration error - check your configs, you may have malformed XML somewhere.

Comment: phuzi that is what I did in the past hours :\

Comment: So... it was working when running from Visual Studio but now you've published it to IIS and it's not working. You need to enable detailed errors and try again how you do that may depend on the version of IIS.

Comment: phuzi - the application is published and deployed on the server. If I run the application directly on the server from wwwroot/Application.exe then a console is opening with localhost:5000 port, if I access this url the application is working(locally on the server). But I want on open the site //domainname:80 the app to work

Comment: Not sure how that changes my comment. Have you enabled detailed error pages?

Comment: Screenshot of the detail error I already have it in the post localhost - link

Comment: That's not a detailed error... A detailed error would likely show a piece of code or XML that is causing the error to be shown.

Comment: Deployment under IIS is quite different as compared to what you get through visual studio. Are you familiar with configuration process under IIS? Are you sure you have got all permissions set correct? If you are doing this on your local machine, it matters what roles/permissions your IIS is running under. If this is different machine and it is not configured for public hosting then you have even more complex problem.

Comment: All of this is well documented but given new ways of hosting its not touched that frequently. Familiarse yourself with IIS configuration. Here is a starting point - https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-create-websites-virtual-directories-iis.html

Comment: Also, if you have access to server on which your IIS is running, take a peek at system and application logs. IIS puts all error details in there, you might get hint. Most likely it is going to be permissions issue.

Comment: I gave all users permissions to read-write to wwwroot, web.config, applicationhost.config and that didn't solve the problem. I suspect it's windows 2022 bug

Comment: @Maria - It is very less likely that it is a bug in the OS. Configuring anything under IIS is utter pain if you do not know internals of how everything ties together. Simplest strategy is to start with wider permissions and narrow them down to restricted scope that your application actually needs. Start with an administrator user, configure every service under it and make it work first **if this is not production**. In short, dry run your deployment configuration in a controlled environment first.

Comment: Btw, is there anything appearing in your server logs? Launch Event Viewer, take a look at nodes under Windows Logs. There should be four logs - Application log (if anything is failing inside your application, it should occur here), Security log (this is where permissions related issues will occur), Setup logs and System logs (this is where you are likely to get most of the failures that are occurring in IIS and other sub systems that it uses). Restart IIS, and your application, and then take a look at logs.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Navigate to `%WINDIR%\system32\inetsrv\config\`
2. Create a backup copy of the file `applicationhost.config` and save it to a different location.
3. Open the `applicationhost.config` in Notepad.
4. Search for the following entry and Remove or disable the XPress compression schema from the configuration using the command below:

   ```
   %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-[name='xpress']
   ```
5. Verify if the compression schema has been removed form the `applicationhost.config`.
6. Save the `applicationhost.config` and restart IIS services.